# Unable to Push to Google Container Registry (unable to access the repository)

Tags: google-container-registry

Whenever I attempt to push a container to the Google Container Registry from my local machine, I get the following error:

> denied: Unable to access the repository; please check that you have permission to access it.

If I open the Cloud Shell, I can push containers with no problems. I have tried doing "gcloud auth login" several times and it seems to make no difference. I don't have any problems running other gcloud commands locally. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Today faced it ... This happened as I chose Asia data center from command line ... To resolve I deleted the project and created a new one and followed https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/locations and chose datacenter us-central and it resolved the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FYI for other customers running into similar issues:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22910

There exists a bug with current versions of the Docker client (1.11, 1.12), and the default credential stores which are being enabled on new installations, which break private registries. Removing the

```
"credsStore": "whatever"
```

field from your docker config (e.g. ~/.docker/config.json) and running

```
gcloud docker ...
```

should fix the issue.

**Update:**

Alternately, we've implemented a credential helper of our own which solves the problem **for our customers** (i.e. doesn't get tripped up by the lack of a scheme in the GCR URLs that the Docker client uses to request credentials).
To install the credential helper:

- Download the helper binary and put it on your PATH

  - `gcloud components install docker-credential-gcr`
    or
  - [download/compile the binary from GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/docker-credential-gcr/releases)
- Execute `docker-credential-gcr configure-docker` to configure to the Docker client

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I'm very impressed by the support I received from Google on this issue (even though it wasn't really your issue).

Comment: We aim to please!

Comment: OMG! why didn't i see this earlier.. spent 3 days trying to upload an docker image to my google container registry with no success. Thanks a lot!

Comment: it's entirely unclear to me if I should be able to push up a docker image from my office laptop into GCR. i've seen some people advise running this whole process from a google server (ec2 instance basically).

Comment: You should be able to push to GCR from anywhere that you can run Docker.

Comment: Using docker-credential-gcr for solving this particular issue is not required anymore is this correct ? Probably most people having authentication issues have (like me :) forgotten to allow both `container engine admin` AND `cloud storage admin` for the service account

Comment: I can't find the `container engine admin` role. In fact there's no `container engine` section in the roles. It works if I set the service account role to `Project -> Editor`, which is less than ideal. So it works without docker-credential-gcr, but I can't find the proper roles.

Comment: @RedShift looks like it was moved under the `Kubernetes Engine` category during the rename. If you just want to pull (and/or push) images to GCR, `Storage Object Viewer` (or `Storage Admin`) is all you need: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control

Comment: Confirmed that Storage Admin suffices to pull and push images.

Answer (score 2):

Have you run gcloud auth login?

Comment: Thank you mate. You saved my night!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like gcloud might not know which project to associate you as.

You can run

> gcloud info

to verify which project gcloud is using.

If it doesn't list the project that you are pushing the image under, you can specify it with the --project flag like

> gcloud --project= docker push ...

To set the default project for gcloud, you can run

> gcloud config set project

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The project is set. I went ahead and set it again just to be safe but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, nothing solved it until I completely removed the folders listed under `gcloud info` (the install and config directories) then reinstalled the sdk.

Then ran `gcloud components install docker-credential-gcr` and set that back up. Everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an updated answer: I wanted to push to eu.gcr.io. Therefore, I need to authenticate to *that* registry (took me a while to figure that out).

So first:

```
docker login -e 1234@5678.com -u oauth2accesstoken -p "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://eu.gcr.io
```

Second:

```
 gcloud docker -- push eu.gcr.io/myProjectName/myComputeMachineName
```

Using cygwin on windows 10 pro (on Hyper-V) and these versions:

```
$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 148.0.0
bq 2.0.24
bq-nix 2.0.24
core 2017.03.17
core-nix 2017.02.28
gcloud
gcloud-deps 2017.02.28
gcloud-deps-linux-x86_64 2017.02.28
gsutil 4.23
gsutil-nix 4.22
```

and

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 17.03.1-ce-rc1, build 3476dbf
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to use GCP on a personal projet :

A look at the activity tab in GCP console showed me that I was trying to push with my professional email address (not allowed on the project) even if I just logged in with my personal one using :

```
gcloud auth login
```

The reason was that I also ran a few months ago this command :

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

with my professional email address.

I just had to run it again, log in with my personal address and everything worked fine !