# docker-credential-gcr not found inside Docker image although executable is there

Tags: docker, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to build a Docker image for my Gitlab CI pipeline containing docker client + gcloud along with the following gcloud components:

- kubectl
- docker-credential-gcr

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM docker:git

RUN mkdir /opt \
    && cd /opt \
    && wget -q https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-152.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzf google-cloud-sdk-152.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz \
    && rm google-cloud-sdk-152.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz \
    && ln -s /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud /usr/bin/gcloud \
    && apk -q update \
    && apk -q add python \
    && apk add --update libintl \
    && apk add --virtual build_deps gettext \
    && cp /usr/bin/envsubst /usr/local/bin/envsubst \
    && apk del build_deps \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && echo "y" | gcloud components install kubectl docker-credential-gcr \
    && ln -s /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/kubectl /usr/bin/kubectl \
    && ln -s /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/docker-credential-gcr /usr/bin/docker-credential-gcr
```

Inside my CI flow, I need to run docker-credential-gcr (because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277986/unable-to-push-to-google-container-registry-unable-to-access-the-repository)).

The `docker-credential-gcr` executable is correctly installed inside `/opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin` like shown by running `docker run -i -t gitlabci-test ls /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin`

[image: first command screenshot]

It is also correctly simlinked inside `/usr/bin` as shown by `docker run -i -t gitlabci-test ls -la /usr/bin`

[image]

And yet, trying to call it with any of the methods below fails miserably

```
docker run -i -t gitlabci-test docker-credential-gcr
docker run -i -t gitlabci-test /usr/bin/docker-credential-gcr
docker run -i -t gitlabci-test /opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/docker-credential-gcr
```

Error message:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 20: docker-credential-gcr: not found
```

On the other hand, running the kubectl component works fine

```
docker run -i -t gitlabci-test kubectl version
```

[image]

Any idea how I can fix this issue to be able to run docker-credential-gcr with the container ?